# How do we capitalize certain letters in a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

So, My doubt is how do we capitalize certain letters in a string.

eg - 'python' , how to capitalize 3rd(t) and 5th(o)

Thank you :)

(Python language)

Comment: And what are your attempts ?

Answer (score 0):

```
In [67]: mystring = ''                                                                                                                        

In [68]: for index, item in enumerate('python'): 
    ...:     if index == 2 or index == 4: 
    ...:         mystring +='python'[index].capitalize() 
    ...:     else:     
    ...:         mystring += item 
    ...:                                                                                                                                      

In [69]: mystring                                                                                                                             
Out[69]: 'pyThOn'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Non-Keyword Arguments(*args)` to pass arguments.

Here is a simple demo.

```
def capitalize(str, *args):
    for index in args:
        str = str.replace(str[index], str[index].upper())
    return str

print(capitalize('python',2,4))
```

Answer (score 0):

You would try the following logic

```
def capitalise(text,indexes):
   temp = list(text) 
   for i in indexes: 
       temp[i] = temp[i].upper() 
   return(''.join(temp))
```

and call the above function using

```
 capitalize(text,index_list)
```

> where, text is the string whose letters are to be capitalised
> and index_list is list of indexes.